# Need a sql query to find all 3 part names with spaces in 'customer info' table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

My "customer info" table contains a column 'name' where the full name of the customer is given (with a space between the parts). Basically, I need to find all the customers with a 3 part name like "King George V" or "Duke of York" - that is, anybody who has more than a first name and last name.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
FROM CustomerInfo
WHERE  length(Custfullname) - length(replace(Custfullname, ' ', '')) >2
```

This is not perfect,it just selects the names where empty spaces are >2